# Why is the action listener not triggering?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener

I know a noob question.. but why is the JOptionPane not triggering when I fill in `tf1` and press enter?

Window class:

```java
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import lombok.Getter;

@Getter
public class Window extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextField tf1, tf2, tf3;
    private JButton b1, b2;
    private JLabel l1;
    private static EventHandler handler;

    Window() {

        super("Calcuator");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        handler = new EventHandler();


        tf1 = new JTextField(30);
        tf2 = new JTextField(30);
        tf3 = new JTextField(20);

        tf1.setToolTipText("Enter the first number");
        tf2.setToolTipText("Enter the second number");
        tf3.setEditable(false);

        b1 = new JButton("Addition");
        b2 = new JButton("Subtraction");

        l1 = new JLabel("The result of the operation is: ");

        tf1.addActionListener(handler);
        tf2.addActionListener(handler);

        add(tf1);
        add(tf2);
        add(b1);
        add(b2);
        add(l1);
        add(tf3);

    }

}
```

EventHandler class:

```java
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class EventHandler implements ActionListener {

    private static Window win = new Window();

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource() == win.getTf1())
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ok");

    }



}
```

Comment: Guess it is triggering. Condition is wrong e.getSource() == win.getTf1()

Comment: So how to solve the issue?

Comment: @user85421 I want to use the action command value later for calculation, so I can't change it now. It has to be user defined

Comment: @Oleksandr so what is the correct condition.

Comment: Pass in EventHandler the reference to parent window.  In other words you need to init win in the constructor of EventHandler. Don't create new Window object, just pass it. this.win = win; EventHandler (Window win)